# Access - Computed / Calculated field that's the sum of a related table column

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've developed a quick and dirty MS Access 2010 `.accdb` database for me to store my store receipts.

I have two main tables and I have set up a one-to-many relationship between `Receipts` and `Items`.

```
Receipts ( ReceiptId, DateTime, GrandTotal )
Items ( ItemId, ReceiptId, Description, LineTotal )
```

I'd like to add a Computed Column to the `Receipts` table that is the `SUM()` of all of that receipt's `Items.LineTotal`, which will allow me to detect discrepancies between a receipt's stated total and the amount I actually paid (such as tips on pizza deliveries).

When I open the table designer for `Receipts` and add a Calculated Column I don't see the `Items` table listed in the Expression Builder. I've made a screenshot: [image].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculated field can not reference fields in a different table.  See [Add a calculated field to a table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-HA101820564.aspx):

*In Access 2010, you can create table fields that calculate values. The calculations can include values from fields in the same table as well as built-in Access functions.*

*NOTES*

*- The calculation cannot include fields from other tables or queries.*

Consider whether a query to supply the calculated field would be an acceptable alternative.  Or, with a form or report, you could add a control and use its control source property to perform the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a macro that fires a query.  It is a relational database.  Do you want to view the data directly from the table? I don't know a lot about Access, but I would probably use a query and sum the lines on grouped receipts.